# How to add python panel date range slider on_change event?

Tags: python, python-3.x, plotly, panel

I am trying to use a dateRangeSlider to pick start and end dates and plot the graph accordingly using plotly in python.

Here, whenever I change the slider, how can I know that slider is updated (return currently selected date-range as tuple) and I need to update the plot X and Y axis ranges? Is there any event handler or a way to use a callback function?

Basically I want to know if dateRangeSlider is changed/updated and then I will pick the data in that range from a DataFrame and plot it using plotly.

**EDIT**: Added code with output image

```py
import datetime as dt
import panel as pn
import yfinance as yf

pn.extension()

# Data part
vix_tickers = ['AUDJPY=X']

df = yf.download(vix_tickers,
                 auto_adjust=True, #only download adjusted data
                 progress=False,
            )
df = df[["Close"]]

# Date Range Slider
date_range_slider = pn.widgets.DateRangeSlider(
    name='Date Range Slider',
    sizing_mode="stretch_width",
    margin = [10,40],
    bar_color = "blue",
    start=df.index[0], end=df.index[-1],
    value=(df.index[0], df.index[-1]),
)

# A Plot
import plotly.graph_objs as go

fig = go.Figure()
df.sort_index(ascending=True, inplace=True)

trace = go.Scatter(x=list(df.index), y=list(df.Close))
fig.add_trace(trace)

fig.update_layout(
    dict(
        title="Time series with range slider and selectors",
        xaxis=dict(
            rangeselector=dict(
                buttons=list(
                    [
                        dict(count=1, label="1m", step="month", stepmode="backward"),
                        dict(count=6, label="6m", step="month", stepmode="backward"),
                        dict(count=1, label="YTD", step="year", stepmode="todate"),
                        dict(count=1, label="1y", step="year", stepmode="backward"),
                        dict(step="all"),
                    ]
                )
            ),
            rangeslider=dict(visible=False),
            type="date",
        ),
    )
)
fig.show()

date_range_slider
```

[image]

Comment: Please add minimal code to reproduce your problem.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for reply. I have added code in the original question as edit. Please have a look! :)

Comment: You want to link the output of rangeslider to the plotly, right? But first you have problem with the getting the range of this slider?

Comment: I can get the range (start, end) of the slider using `date_range_slider.value` but how can I know that range slider is moved and hence I can now update the plotly chart by using start, end values got from `date_range_slider.value`. So yes I want to link output of rangeslider to the plotly!

Comment: I want to plot a new graph with (start, end) dates value range - subset of original data within that start-end range in place of original plot.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249858/discussion-between-pratik-ghodke-and-hamzah).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use [ipywidgets](https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user_install.html) instead of panel, it is easier and more powerful:

```
import datetime as dt
import pandas as pd
import yfinance as yf
import plotly.graph_objs as go
from ipywidgets import interact
from ipywidgets import widgets


# Data part
vix_tickers = ['AUDJPY=X']

df = yf.download(vix_tickers,
                 auto_adjust=True, #only download adjusted data
                 progress=False,
            )
df = df[["Close"]]

df.sort_index(ascending=True, inplace=True)

widgets.SelectionRangeSlider(
    options=df.index,
    description='Dates',
    orientation='horizontal',
    layout={'width': '1000px'}
    
    
@interact
def read_values(
    slider = widgets.SelectionRangeSlider(
    options=df.index,
     index=(0, len(df.index) - 1),
    description='Dates',
    orientation='horizontal',
    layout={'width': '500px'},
    continuous_update=False
)
):
    fig = go.Figure()
    trace = go.Scatter(x=list(df.index), y=list(df.Close))
    fig.add_trace(trace)
    fig.update_xaxes(range=[slider[0], slider[1]])
    go.FigureWidget(fig.to_dict()).show()
```

**Output**
[image]

Comment: Thanks man, This is really amazing. Everything is working as expected except one thing! Everytime I touch the slider, new graph is plotted! Slider is stuck to 1st chart and new charts are getting appended below the first one. Can you tell me where did you run the code? I mean jupyter-notebook, kaggle, colab, vscode? I am using vscode. Again this is Amazing :)

Comment: @PratikGhodke I am using Jupyternotebook. If the answer works with you, please accept and vote up the answer:)

Comment: Thanks for the help! Please vote up question as well if you liked working on it! Have a good day!